# Is human thought itself a fundamental force?

Tags: philosophy-of-physics, physics, thought-experiment

To begin with, as far as I understand, there are four well accepted forces of nature:

1. Gravity
2. Weak interaction
3. Strong interaction
4. Electromagnetism

Now, these forces are all characterized by changing physical motion and are typically considered to be transmitted by some particle or field. So, could one consider the human body as the transmitter and the human action as a force itself? I feel it could but at the same time it is paradoxical.

I say it is paradoxical because if I am to do an action such as lifting the book, then every single thing I feel when lifting a book could be described almost completely (roughly speaking) by forces 1. and 4. (see  [for instance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/126513/236734)). But, at the same time, the thing which began all these forces was my initial thought of lifting this book, so would my thought be a transmitter of force beyond physical forces itself?

Comment: Not just "human action" but probably all action of living organisms.

Comment: Human thought can be reduced to other interactions, then it is not _fundamental_. In any case, according to the definition, thought is not even a _force_.

Comment: My vote for a fifth force is Love.

Comment: @ScottRowe Question then is, what kind of boson mediates the love force? Spin-1? Opposites attract? Spin-2? We love who we find sameness with? :D

Answer (score 2):

I think it's an interesting question in relation to certain interpretations of free will. In Perti's, answer, the lifting of the book is the end result of a chain of causes and events that are linked by electrical forces, but the very start of the chain may be a thought. The question then is how does the thought appear to trigger the electrical impulses that propagate to the responsible muscles to lift the book. If you don't believe in a separate mind, then it is easy- you just say that electrical forces determine the movement of electrons and ions in the brain, that the movement gives rise to the illusion of freewill and to the corresponding generation of other movements of electrons and ions which signal the decision to lift the book. However, that suggests that thoughts in the mind arise from the changing configuration of particles in the brain, and it is hard (for me at least) to see how thoughts in themselves could change the configuration of particles in the brain unless you introduce a new class of force. And that seems to hammer a very large nail into the coffin of free will, if you take free will as meaning that the human mind can act independently of the electrical forces that govern the dynamic configuration of the matter that constitutes our brains.

Comment: Free Will is like a vampire, it takes a wooden stake or silver bullet to kill it. You never see it in the daytime.

Answer (score 0):

No, human action is not another fundamental force. Human actions are just regular kinetic forces produced by the muscles.

I think you might be approaching the question of what *causes* human actions. Does the decision to act cause the action (mental causation)? Or does the energy flow in the bloodstream cause the action?

Anyway, the mind controls the muscles, that is obvious. But apparently control is not the same thing as causation, as control does not provide the energy for the action.

Then again, we do seem to self-cause our voluntary actions. Minds do the controlling and bodies provide the energy.

Comment: I mentioned all these points in the subject and the rebuttals to them as well. Have enough read the questin?

Comment: @trystwithfreedom maybe there is nothing more to say about it?